# Key prop with es6 classes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am running through a tutorial on pluralsight (course was made a while ago) on React so some things are a bit outdated, such as Babel. However, I ran into something that I'm unsure of. I get this message in the browser console:

*Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `App`.*

Thanks in advance.

Below is my App component:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      messages: [
        'hi there, how are you?',
        'I am fine, and you?'
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    var messageNodes = this.state.messages.map(message => {
      return (
        <div>{message}</div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>{messageNodes}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: One of these probably would have helped too: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breactjs%5D+Each+child+in+an+array+or+iterator+should+have+a+unique+%22key%22+prop.  Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: This should clarify a lot: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each repeatable item needs (needs in the sense that it improves performance) some kind of unique identifier.

In the case below, you can just add an the index of the array as the key, however as your app gets bigger, you might want to give those messages some kind of id (probably coming from a database or similar).

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      messages: [
        'hi there, how are you?',
        'I am fine, and you?'
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    var messageNodes = this.state.messages.map(message, index => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>{message}</div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>{messageNodes}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

An example of something bigger might be:

```
messages: [
    { id: 234, text: "Hi there, how are you?" }, 
]
```

Comment: That clears it up and makes a lot of sense! Thank you!

Comment: Using index as an id is okay if you never remove or add items except at the end of the array, and never sort the array. That is to say, it's brittle.

Comment: 100% agree - but given the given data input, Jose could use either that or the message itself - both brittle. I would recommend, as part of my extended answer at the bottom, to have id's coming from persistence layer